# drupal Block Config option not showing in main page

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

Hi I am logging as admin but block config option icon is not showing on top right corner of every block. I have to opt a long route to configure the blocks. plz help.

Comment: Please specify your question more this is not very informative

Comment: when you login as admin, you can configure and blocks in the main page, the top right corner wheel icon. I updated the core Drupal using update module, but now that config icon is not showing up.

Comment: its Drupal-7 version i am using

Answer (score 0):

check your style file you may add display:none to it or any style conflict with it

Answer (score 0):

most likely it's a theme issue, try to switch to one of the themes that shipped with Drupal, and check if they show up.. if not please post a link or some screenshots. and let us know what theme do you use.

Comment: I have tried all the options listed above. Most importantly, change of theme should resolve it but no luck as of now. I have added a temporary admin account on my testsite. please use the information below to take a look at the issue. site-name: http://pksavings.com/ login: admin_guest passwd: california2013

Comment: thanks, problem has solved... I have disabled the themer devl module and everything is working fine now!

Answer (score 0):

In the module configuration page ( /admin/modules ), make sure that the following module is enabled :

```
Contextual links (contextual)
```

I had the same issue and re-enabling this module solved the issue.